# I am trying to deserialize a JSON into a list of objects using .NET 3.1

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have the following Json:

```
{
   "Id":"2727",
   "Region":"US",
   "Data":[
      {
         "Title":"Director",
         "JobDescription":"Coordinates the department activity",
         "Department":"HR"
      },
      {
         "Title":"Programmer",
         "JobDescription":"Enterprise software developer",
         "Department":"FR"
      }
   ]
}
```

My format looks like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}

public class Format
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public List<Data> Data {get; set;}
}
```

I have tried to deserialize it like this:

```
var  objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Format>>(File.ReadAllText("mockJson.json")).ToList();
```

I am getting this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
> Newtonsoft.Json.dll Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
> {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[JSONParsingExample.Format]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'GlobalOrgId', line 2,
> position 15.

Comment: You don't have a list of `Format`s in your JSON. It's just a single object. If you expect to have a list, you need to surround your JSON with "[]". And that's exactly what the error message is trying to tell you quite verbosely.

Comment: Just to clarify what @Fildor means, change `DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Format>>` to `DeserializeObject<Format>` and it will work fine. Or, if you intended to have a list of `Format`s, wrap the json in an array: `[ *your json* ]`.

Comment: Thank you, the second option solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this as an answer because I think its worth making it more visible. I assumed the method call was going to have some issues with nesting lists inside a json, but I'm pleased to see it works.

```
Format format = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Format>(File.ReadAllText("mockJson.json"));
```

I inspected the elements and they all seem to be where they are supposed to be.

Just be careful because `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` returns an object of type `T`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

When working with JSON in .NET I'd recommend moving over to the new built in stuff.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/